# How does the norm of one element relate to ramification of primes?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am currently working through Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* and I am stuck on question 2 from chapter 13. The question states: Let $F$ be a real quadratic field. Show that if $F$ has an element of norm $-1$ then no prime $p \equiv 3 $ $(4)$ is ramified. So far I've shown that if there is an element with norm $-1$, then $a^2 - b^2d = -1$ for some rationals $a, b$. Furthermore, I know that if $p$ divides $\delta_F$ (the discriminant of $F$) then it ramifies. I have also proven that if $d \equiv 2, 3 (4)$ then $\delta_F = 4d$ & if $d \equiv 1 (4)$ then $\delta_F = d$. I am unsure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ is a prime dividing $d$, does $a^2 - b^2d \equiv -1 \bmod p$ have a solution?

Comment: Thank you for your help - I finally solved it with this hint!